# Username and Password must match to data in text file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have designed a username and password program. When the user enters their username and password, it should check if it matches the data in a text file. The problem is that it displays access denied when I input the correct username and password. Please help me find a solution.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):

        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):


        self.instruction = Label(self,text='Enter your Username')
        self.instruction.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky=W)

        self.username=Entry(self)
        self.username.grid(row=1, column =1, sticky=W)

        self.sumbit_button=Button(self,text='Submit',command= self.reveal)
        self.sumbit_button.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.instruction = Label(self,text='Enter a password')
        self.instruction.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky=W)

        self.password=Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row=4, column =1, sticky=W)

        self.text = Text(self,width=35, height=5, wrap=WORD)
        self.text.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky=W)


    def reveal(self):
        file=open('data.RTF','r')
        data1=file.readlines()
        file.close

        content2=self.username.get()
        content=self.password.get()


        if content2==(data1[0]) and content==(data1[1]): 
            message='You have access to something special.'

        else:
            message='Access denied.'

        self.text.delete(0.0,END)
        self.text.insert(0.0,message)

root=Tk()
root.title('Username and Password')
root.geometry('250x150')
app=Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when you save it to your file it will add the new line escape sequence at the end "\n". Use .replace("\n","") before the comparison

Comment: Could you possibly show me I am unsure where to put this sorry

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, your use of the index `0.0` is incorrect. Text indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. Also, the index of the first character is 1.0. 0.0 works, but only because tkinter is a bit liberal in what it accepts.

Comment: You could use data1[0].strip("\n) to remove the new line escape sequence

Comment: Unfortunately it  doesn't work. When i tried data1[0].strip("\n) it did not work and when i changed the index it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code to show where to do this, adding a comment on the line before.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):

        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):


        self.instruction = Label(self,text='Enter your Username')
        self.instruction.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky=W)

        self.username=Entry(self)
        self.username.grid(row=1, column =1, sticky=W)

        self.sumbit_button=Button(self,text='Submit',command= self.reveal)
        self.sumbit_button.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.instruction = Label(self,text='Enter a password')
        self.instruction.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky=W)

        self.password=Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row=4, column =1, sticky=W)

        self.text = Text(self,width=35, height=5, wrap=WORD)
        self.text.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky=W)


    def reveal(self):
        file=open('data.RTF','r')
        data1=file.readlines()
        file.close

        content2=self.username.get()
        content=self.password.get()

        # Code updated on next line
        if content2==(data1[0].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")) and content==(data1[1].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")): 
            message='You have access to something special.'

        else:
            message='Access denied.'

        self.text.delete(0.0,END)
        self.text.insert(0.0,message)

root=Tk()
root.title('Username and Password')
root.geometry('250x150')
app=Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is still displaying access denied I am unsure why

Comment: It worked for me when I tested it, are you sure you entered what you have put in the data.rtf file?

Comment: depending how you created you rtf file, you may need to change "\n" to "\r\n". I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: yes I am sure they are in the same file and i have tested  this a few times now

Comment: I believe there was a problem with the file itself I used a .txt file instead and it worked thank you